# JavaScript steps for object creation and function invocation

Tags: javascript

Let we have a simple script snippet:

```
var foo=function(){ return 'a'; };//1
var bar={prop:foo()};//2
alert(bar.prop);//3
```

At what line `foo` Function code is executing? At 2 or at 3? Please give me a specification proof/link if it possible.

Is it true that when the interpreter finds `_some_name()` internal method `[[Call]]` will be invoked?

Comment: 2, but im not sure why you need any proof - its pretty obvious!

Comment: At 2, of course. You _invoke_ function by placing `()` after its name.

Comment: A function is ran when it's called with `()`.  So, `foo()` is being ran on line 2.  `bar.prop` is being set to a string, not a function.

Comment: @Jamiec It's not obvious for me. I'm update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 2.

Line 1 is where foo is defined.  Line 2 is where it is invoked.

Comment: And the link the OP requested: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3

Comment: @T.J. Crowder many thanks, that's what i need! But i have once more question: Is it true that when interpretator found token such that `CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments` the steps of 11.2.3 will be executed?

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes, but fair warning, the terminology and notation used in the spec are very hard to read unless you really study the bits on notation at the outside. In particular, don't get the impression that there's a colon (`:`) involved. There isn't, that's just now the notation being used defines the term *CallExpression*. `foo()` is a call expression (note there's no colon anywhere). Just like you might write "Car: A common vehicle typically with four wheels and an enclosed cabin."

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Can you get an example of CallExpression: `CallExpression Arguments`. It's hard to imagine that.

Comment: @St.Antario: `foo("bar")`

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following examples

```js
var foo = function() { return 'a<br />'; };
var bar = { prop: foo() }; // foo is invoked here and 'a' assigned to bar.prop
document.body.innerHTML += bar.prop;


var baz = { prop: foo }; // foo is assigned to baz.prop
document.body.innerHTML += baz.prop(); // foo is invoked here
```